Help to understand summing circuit I have
I have the following schematic using four 40106 inverters as oscillators, which are summed into an inverting op-amp configuration using copper plates and finger resistance.

How can I understand what is happening in the circuit? The 40106 is oscillating between 0V and +9V, and there is a reference voltage of Vcc/2 at the non-inverting input of the op-amp. How is the output voltage calculated?
Thanks for any clarifications!

I have the following schematic
Is it an existing circuit? Are you trying to design a circuit, or analyze an existing one? Edit the question to make it clear. You had the schematic, now we have it too, and we don't know anything about it.

You can't calculate the output voltage without knowing the resistance of your finger. The resistance of your finger determines the voltage gain, and the resistance of a finger placed on two copper plates is determined by moisture, used pressure, oxidation of th copper, etc, so it is highly variable and unknown so you can't have any specific value in a calculation. Otherwise, that's simply a bog-standard single supply inverting op-amp summing circuit.

If you designed the circuit: please share how you thought about it. Why did you design it this way? What should the circuit do? If you're analyzing an existing circuit: do you only have a schematic, or was the circuit assembled? Does it work? How well does it work? How close it is to your requirements, i.e. does it work as you  want it to, or not quite?


How is the output voltage calculated?

Add the fingers into the circuit. You wanted to model them as resistors:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But I'm not sure if that's what you want. In fact, the circuit looks like it was designed not for resistive coupling, but for capacitive coupling. That's because fingers can be quite good conductors, and the circuit is super-sensitive. There can be only about ±3μA of current flowing into/out of the inverting pin of the op-amp before its output saturates!
Typically, for touch sensing, you want to:

Cover the electrodes with a dielectric

Use interdigitated electrode patterns (look it up!)


So the circuit will then become:

simulate this circuit
In either case, the output of the op-amp is 1V/μA of input current, with the inverting input node assumed fixed at 4.5V. It doesn't matter if the currents are sourced through the resistors or capacitors.
The op-amp you are using can only swing to within about ±2V of either supply rail. So you can assume that the output would be in the range from ≈+2V to ≈+7V.

the question I should ask is why using the summing opamp and not passive summing? meaning connecting all the resistors that at the inverting pin straight to the output(audio mixer)

@Omer You should ask the question you want answered. Right now this answers the question you asked.
